# pymongo query for all items containing a unique identifier

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a mongo collection with data structure in the follwoing way

```
       content: {'description': {   'text': [{'_date': '2019-05-21','_sectionId': 'a13a','_objectId: 'f637cee'},
{'_date': '2019-05-21','_objectId': '8b2ed183', '_source: 'f637cee'},
{ etc....}
{'_date': '2019-05-21','_sectionId': 'a13a','_objectId: 'XXXcee'}
},
'client' : {.....},
}
```

I am looking for the way to query the collection to get a list of tuples  in the following way:
given a section Id I would like to get the corresponding 'objectId'

In this case the result would be:

```
 ('a13a','f637cee'), ('a13a','XXXcee')
```

I started to do something like this:

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(mongoconnection)
print('databases names:')
myclient.list_database_names()
# getting the collection:
mydb = myclient["clients"]
query = {'content.description.text._sectionId': 'a13a'}
cur = mydb.find(query)
```

But I dont know how to extract the information from the cursor.

Some help?

Note the info might be nested in different places, i.e. there are more nodes preceding "content" that can vary.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second parameter of the `find()` to get required fields.

**Ex:**

```
query = {'content.description.text._sectionId': 'a13a'}
cur = mydb.find(query, { "_id": 0, "_sectionId": 1, "_objectId": 1 })
print([tuple(i.values()) for i in cur])
```